# A strange behaviour of Class.getResource()

Tags: java, netbeans, resources, classloader

I have a NetBeans project. In the project directory, I've created some additional directories for keeping resources (images). So the path of one of my images is "/res/imgs/on.png" ("res" and everything in it is created by me). Then I've added the "res" directory to my project's sources (Right-click on my project in NetBeans -> Properties -> Sources -> Add Folder (for Source Packages Folder section)). And I've accessed to the URL of the image in my project using the following code:

```
URL url = Class.class.getResource("/imgs/on.png");
```

And this was successful - just a few days ago. Today, after this code execution, url variable was set to null. But when the code was modified to this:

```
URL url = Class.class.getResource("/imgs");
```

The (url != null) was true.

Next, I've created a yet another project, where I've done exactly the same manipulations (that is, created subdirectories in the project folder, loaded some files to it and tried to execute a code, similar to these I've written above). And these manipulations were successful. After that, I've returned to my first project (that initialized url to null when tried to access "/imgs/on.png"). And it turned out, that everything was again OK there and the image's URL loaded successfully...

So, the question is, what was the problem? Is this a NetBeans bug, or maybe I'm doing something in a wrong way?

Comment: "My code *doesn't work*, I have **no idea** why.. My code *works*, I have **no idea** why"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably by some Netbeans compile/clean glitch, the "on.png" was not in the classes directory and therefore was not found on the classpath. After a restart or any operation that would cause Netbeans to rescan the source folders, it was back there.

By the way instead of `Class.class.getResource()` you should use the caller's class, e.g. `this.getClass().getResource()` to use the same class loader.